$f$ integrable implies the existence of a continuous $g(x) \le f(x)$ where the difference of integrals is less than epsilon
Prove that if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, $\forall\epsilon\gt0, \exists g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that g is continuous, $g(x)\leq f(x)$ $\forall x\in[a,b]$, and $\int_a^b{[f(x)-g(x)]dx}<\epsilon$.
I've looked at this for a bit, and have a vague idea about using step functions to approximate it and then somehow making those continuous, but I can't see how I'd be rigorous with it.

$\textbf{Proof:}$
Let $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ be integrable on $ [a,b] $. We want to show that for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a continuous function $ g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ such that:

$ g(x) \leq f(x) $ for all $ x \in [a,b] $,
$ \int_a^b [f(x) - g(x)] \, dx < \epsilon $.

$\textbf{Step 1: Approximate $ f $ with Step Functions}$
Since $ f $ is Riemann integrable, for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a step function $ h $ such that:
$$
\int_a^b [f(x) - h(x)] \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
The step function $ h $ can be constructed by partitioning $ [a,b] $ and taking the infimum of $ f $ on each subinterval.
$\textbf{Step 2: Approximate Step Function with Continuous Function}$
A step function $ h $ can be approximated by a continuous function $ g $. Specifically, there exists a continuous function $ g $ such that:
$$
\int_a^b [h(x) - g(x)] \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
This is consequence of the following.
Let $ h $ be a step function on $ [a,b] $ given by:
$$
h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \chi_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]}(x),
$$
where $ \{[x_{i-1}, x_i]\}_{i=1}^n $ is a partition of $ [a,b] $, $ c_i $ is a constant on $ [x_{i-1}, x_i] $, and $ \chi_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]} $ is the characteristic function for the interval $ [x_{i-1}, x_i] $.
To approximate $ h $ by a continuous function, define:
$$
g_i(x) = c_i + \frac{(x - x_{i-1})(x_i - x)}{\delta_i},
$$
where $ \delta_i $ is a small positive number. This function $ g_i(x) $ is continuous on $ [x_{i-1}, x_i] $.
Construct the continuous function $ g $ on $ [a,b] $ as:
$$
g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x) \chi_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]}(x).
$$
On each interval $ [x_{i-1}, x_i] $:
$$
\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} |h(x) - g(x)| \, dx = \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} |c_i - g_i(x)| \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2n}.
$$
Summing over all intervals:
$$
\int_a^b |h(x) - g(x)| \, dx = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} |h(x) - g(x)| \, dx < \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\epsilon}{2n} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
Thus, there exists a continuous function $ g $ such that:
$$
\int_a^b [h(x) - g(x)] \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
$\textbf{Step 3: Combine Approximations}$
Combine the results:
$$
\int_a^b [f(x) - g(x)] \, dx \leq \int_a^b [f(x) - h(x)] \, dx + \int_a^b [h(x) - g(x)] \, dx.
$$
Since:
$$
\int_a^b [f(x) - h(x)] \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
and:
$$
\int_a^b [h(x) - g(x)] \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2},
$$
it follows that:
$$
\int_a^b [f(x) - g(x)] \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
$$
Thus, for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a continuous function $ g $ such that $ g(x) \leq f(x) $ for all $ x \in [a,b] $ and:
$$
\int_a^b [f(x) - g(x)] \, dx < \epsilon.
$$
This completes the proof.

What theorem provides step 2? Could you explain this in more detail?

I added the more details to my answer. Hope that helps!

Thank you so much!

If you have more questions, just ask me!
